# SettingWithCopyWarning & Hidden Chaining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting the SettingWithCopyWarning that suggests that I may have a chaining problem.

> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

I've read about this at length, but cannot seem to find the right solution for my use case. Here's a great article on the topic: [Understanding SettingwithCopyWarning in pandas](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/)

However, I'm still not quite sure how to proceed. Here are three variations of the same line of code that produce the ending result, but all throw up that same error.

Variations:

1. `X[subindex + '_DE'] = X[subindex + '_DE'].clip(lower=0, upper=200, axis=0)`
2. `X.loc[:, subindex + '_DE'] = np.clip(df.loc[:, subindex + '_DE'], 0, 200)`
3. `X.loc[:, subindex + '_DE'] = X.loc[:, subindex + '_DE'].clip(lower=0, upper=200, axis=0)`

End goal: Simply clip (truncate) any values in column [subindex + '_DE'] that extend beyond the lower (0) and upper (200) limits.

I'm not sure how to proceed. A little guidance would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

**Helpful background information:**

X is a pandas dataframe of float64 data arranged in 20 columns (features) x 6514 rows (observations).

Here's some data to work with:

```
> print(X[subindex + '_DE'].head(180))

> date 
> 1999-12-31    33.6584 
> 2000-01-01    33.6584 
> 2000-01-02    33.6584
> 2000-01-03    33.6584
> ... ...
> 2000-06-25    32.6530
> 2000-06-26    32.6530
> 2000-06-27    32.6530
> Name: NYEPLC_DE, Length: 180, dtype: float64
```

Comment: provide some data to work with: X.head(20)

Comment: how is `X` defined?

Comment: Updated original post with answers to both (sharatpc & IanS) questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

In the `def`, I set `X = df[]` (a dataframe). If I simply add `.copy()` to `df[]`, then the warning goes away.

E.g. `X = df[['column1', 'column2']].copy()`

Benjamin Pryke's article above is very good...